# Cardinality of the set of strict total orders on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, order-theory, cardinals

> A strict total order on $\mathbb{R}$ is a relation $R \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ such that:
>
> - $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, (x,x) \not \in R$
> - $\forall x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}, (x,y) \in R \text{ and } (y,z) \in R \implies (x,z) \in R$
> - $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}, x \neq y \implies$ precisely one of $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,x) \in R$ holds
>
> What is the cardinality of the set of strict total orders on $\mathbb{R}$?

Let $E$ be the considered set. Clearly $|E| \leq 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ since $E\subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$ by definition. My intuition says that this is actually an equality of cardinals, but I'm having trouble proving that $2^{2^{\aleph_0}} \leq |E|$. I tried to find an injection from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ to $E$ by defining a strict total order $<_S \in E$ as follows:
$$\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}, x <_S y \iff (x < y \text{ and } x,y \in S) \text{ or } (x < y \text{ and } x,y \not \in S) \text{ or } (x \in S \text{ and } y \not \in S)$$
but this doesn't seem to be injective. I've also tried to consider functions from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \})$ to $E$ instead, but again couldn't find injections.

Comment: Every bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself defines a well order. Now look that $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ has $2^{2^{\aleph_{0}}}$ elements

Comment: @LilMinho77 I've tried to use that as well, by defining a map from the bijections of $\mathbb{R}$ to $E$, but again, I couldn't make this map be injective. Could you please elaborate the construction? What I tried was: for some $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a bijection, define $<_f$ by $x <_f y \iff f(x) < f(y)$

Comment: @LilMinho77 A well-order? I guess so, if we fix a well ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ in advance. But you probably meant a strict total order. Also, it is clear that $|\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}| = 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$, but showing that the set of *bijections* $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ has the same cardinality seems just as difficult as counting the number of strict total orders.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. We need to fix some well ordering of $\mathbb{R}$. But it's no problem on needing CA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea *does* work after all, with a tiny change: Consider only $S$ with $\Bbb Z\subseteq S$ (using the fact that $|\Bbb R|=|\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z|$).
Then $S\mapsto{<_S}$ is injective because we can reconstruct $S$ as
$$\{\,x\in\Bbb R\mid \exists n\in\Bbb Z\colon x<_Sn\,\} $$